# Is there a problem using xdotool to direct keystrokes to Java windows?

Tags: java, xdotool

I'm running Fedora 22 (Linux) and have a Java application written by others that I want to send keystrokes to. I have tried to use xdotool in various ways, but I can neither set focus to the Java app nor send it keystrokes.

The app is started with javaws with the following command line:

```
javaws -J-XX:MaxPermSize=512M -J-d64 -J-Xms1G -J-Xmx1G /path/to/java/file
```

My first attempt to send it keystrokes was with this command:

```
xdotool search --name 'Window title' windowraise windowfocus --sync key H e l l o Return
```

But nothing happened. The Java window did not gain focus or see my keystrokes.

So I looked up the Java process's PID and tried identifying the process by its PID.

```
xdotool search --pid 1234 windowraise windowfocus --sync key H e l l o Return
```

Same result. Finally, I tried identifying the window with 'selectwindow'.

```
xdotool selectwindow windowraise windowfocus --sync key H e l l o Return
```

After issuing the command, the cursor changed to a square. I moved the mouse to the Java window and clicked, but this didn't work either.

To investigate further, I ran a different Java application with the following command:

```
java -jar appname.jar
```

xdotool could not set focus or send keystrokes to this window either.

Having read the xdotool documentation, I know that some programs won't accept its input. Is there something I can do, such as passing different command line arguments, to these Java apps to get them to listen to xdotool's keystrokes?

Here is some information about the versions of Java and xdotool I'm running:

```
$ java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_65-debug"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_65-debug-b17)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.65-b01-debug, mixed mode)

$ xdotool --version
xdotool version 2.20110530.1
```

Comment: `xdottool` is an tool that interacts with X11 windows. Java toolkits do not necessarily create proper X11 windows for every widget (though they must create at least one per top-level window). It might have something to do with that. When you say nothing happens, did you try putting another window on top of that to see whether it gets raised?

Comment: Another possible issue would be that the application (or java or some java setting) deliberately blocks synthetic events. Some applications do this for security.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Window focus is the job of the window manager. I presume you are using one.
The best way to focus a window is:

```
xdotool search --name 'Window title' windowactivate
```

xdotool uses 2 mechanisms to send key events, the `XTEST` extension for events to send to the current focus, and `XSendEvent()` to send events to a given window. The latter generates events with a *synthetic* flag, which some applications decide means it is a security risk, so ignore the event.

However, you can still send "real" key events using xdotool, but you must not explicitly provide a window. After moving the focus to your window, use

```
xdotool type Hello; xdotool key Return
```

Comment: Using your suggestion, I was able to send keystrokes to the Java application's window. However, the window didn't get the keystrokes that I thought I sent. It's an authentication window (don't worry, I'm not sending a password), so maybe it's extra fussy about what characters it accepts. Because the Java application is a black box to me, I'm not going to pursue this further.

Comment: You can try adding `--clearmodifiers` to the `type` and `key` commands to remove any shift or alt or caplock modifier. You can also send the actual keycodes you think the app needs (the letters you give are translated into keycodes anyway) by giving the decimal values, eg `key "38+56+38"` could be "aba" depending on your keyboard mapping.

Comment: It was a good try, but it didn't help. I added `--clearmodifiers` and `key 38` but the result didn't change. Although I only sent one key, the application must have thought I pressed Enter (or it saw something it didn't like) because it immediately displayed an error message.

Comment: Perhaps the window id found by `xdotool search` is not the right one. Apps sometimes have several windows unmapped to optimise their appearance on demand. Try `xwininfo -tree` then click on the java app window, and check that the window ids listed match one from xdotool. You could try sending a key explicitly to each of these ids.

Comment: The `windowactivate` command appears to work: the cursor blinks in a text entry field in the window where I want the keystrokes to go. And when I send a keystroke, the window that I want to receive it reacts--it just reacts the wrong way by giving me an error message. I will try `xwininfo` later today and let you know what I find--can't do it now.

Comment: Ouput of xwininfo: 

xwininfo: Window id: 0x4e000b0 "Security Code Card Authentication"

  Root window id: 0x2c9 (the root window) (has no name)
  Parent window id: 0x1e716ea (has no name)
     2 children:
     0x4e000b4 "FocusProxy": ("Focus-Proxy-Window" "FocusProxy")  1x1+-1+-1  +1455+411
     0x4e000b2 "Content window": ("sun-awt-X11-XContentWindow" "com-sun-javaws-Main")  468x314+-4+-29  +1452+383

When I run `xdotool search "Security Code Card Authentication"`, I get the first window id (0x4e000b0 in this case). Running out of characters here--continued in the next comment.

Comment: When I run `xdotool key --window 81789104` (81789104 = 0x4e000b0), nothing happens. Same with the other window ids. This is probably because xdotool is using `XSendEvent()`. What I haven't figured out is how to set a specific window id with xdotool (`xdotool search --id 81789104` doesn't work.)

Comment: (you should move your xwininfo comment as an edit of your original post). The only thing left I think is `xdotool windowfocus --sync 0x4e000b4 key ...`